# Orchard missing Forms

Tags: orchardcms

I created new page using Orchard CMS and I am missing some elements when creating new content. These elements are under "Forms" group, as you can see in the image. Also, Form Submissions link from dashboard is missing. Do You have any idea how can I install them in my new Orchard page? Thanks for help.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRCNR.png
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDcY3.png

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how do you handle the form submission. You can use `WorkFlow` for this, you can save the content, ... there are many ways.

In your image, you can see `Button` in top. Which will save the form as a content if you have selected `Create Content` in form properties or you can also store into the database by selecting `Store Submission` at same place.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable Dynamic Forms, not custom Forms, if you are on 1.9.x version.

Comment: You are right, but...
When I created new page i downloaded already compiled project from orchard site. Even though dynamic forms were enabled there, I still didnt have an option to add form.
The solution was to download source code from orchard git, build it precompiled, and then set up new site using this build.

Comment: So, it works now? To add a new dynamic form, go to New->Form.

Comment: Yeah, the problem was that the zip file at orchard's website is just an old version.